# What does "AMFI: code signature verification failed" mean during single-user boot, and should I worry?

Tags: high-sierra, startup, single-user

I had to boot into single-user mode for something and during the boot process I noticed repeated error messages, "AMFI: code signature verification failed".

What could be causing these, and is this cause for worry? I’m running Mac OS 10.13.6. See attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: if it doesn't affect you in normal mode, it probably doesn't matter

Comment: [This thread](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/update-to-sierra-ok-booting-only-in-safe-mode-after-first-reboot.203394/) at tonymacx86.com may give some additional elucidation.